# How to fetch all the documents with unique id from firestore database using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestore SS][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI1Dm.png

> I want to fetch each document as displayed in SS it's stored as Pets + unique_userId.
> I am unable to fetch all data together. Just able to fetch one data of a particular user using the code below.

```
const [info,setInfo]=useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("pets ESYXOPqlJpZ48np8LfNivnh9pvc2").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
       setInfo(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
      );    
    },[]);
```

> Here ESYXOPqlJpZ48np8LfNivnh9pvc2 this is the userID of each unique user

**Please help me out to fetch all the Pets data instead of hardcoding and fetching one particular data.**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code,

```
const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,"pets ESYXOPqlJpZ48np8LfNivnh9pvc2"));

      const document =[];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        document.push({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id
        });
      });
      setdocs(document);
  }, []);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but the above code will only fetch data from a single collection. But not all the collections, please refer to the ScreenShot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the appended id is a reference to the owner's id? In this case, would it be an option to fetch the owner list and use everyone's id to build a list of collection ids and then get all of their data?

If not, I only see to options:

1. Rethink your database structure - maybe use a unified `pets` collection and have a reference with/to that `id` in the pet documents.
2. Create a cloud function in which use [@google-cloud/firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore) to get the list of collections. There are tons of resources out there to help you get started with firebase cloud functions. Their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) is pretty good also, and probably the most up-to-date

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

module.exports = functions
  .region('europe-west3') // use the region you want here
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
      const firestore = new Firestore();
      const collections = (await firestore.listCollections()).map(collection => collection.id)

      response.json({ data: collections })
    } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).send(error.message)
    }
})
```

You'll get and endpoint which you can use to fetch the collection ids (e.g.: `https://your-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/collections`)

```
const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
const [collectionIds, setCollectionIds] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://your-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/collections')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(({ data }) => setCollectionIds(data))
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  collectionIds.forEach((collectionId) => {
    // There are better ways to do this,
    // I'm just using your approach so you can focus on the rest of the code
    db.collection(collectionId).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPets((currentPets) => [...currentPets, ...snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())])
    })
  })
}, [collectionIds])
```

Please note that these are very high-level implementations, there's no error handling, no teardowns or anything, so keep that in mind. Hope it helps, good luck!